# Barcode Recognition and Conversion in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am currently working on project Barcode recognition and conversion in Matlab. But during implementation when I crop a line using the imcrop function of Matlab, there is an error, I can't understand the problem, here is a chunk of code:

```
size_image = size(input);
for i=1:size_image(2)
   binary_img1(i)=input(round(size_image(1)/2), i);
end
inv=not(binary_img1)
ind1 = find(inv, 1, 'first');
ind2 = find(inv, 1, 'last');
new_binary_img1=imcrop(binary_img1,[ind1 1 ind2-ind1 0]);
```

Comment: what is `inv`? what is the error?

Comment: inv is NOT of binary image

Comment: The code have two variables that are built-in  matlab function (`inv`, `input`) - should be modified. Could you output `ind1` and `ind2` by removing `;`, and output the size and few value of `binary_img1`?

Comment: what is the error message? Maybe find(inv) returns empty?

Comment: Unable to understand what problem you are getting. However I created a tutorial some days ago you can check at [http://www.addictiveblogs.com/barcode-recognition-and-conversion-in-matlab/](http://www.addictiveblogs.com/barcode-recognition-and-conversion-in-matlab/)

Comment: You don't actually need: the loop to extract binary_img1, to use an inverted image (just look for the first/last zero directly), or to use `imcrop` here - why not just `binary_img1(ind1:ind2)`?